# Bulk upload data with cumulusci

Tags: data, bulk-api, cumulusci

I am trying to bulk upload data with cumulusci.

1. Is there any command to enable bulk mode?
2. Any thing to append in the json while inserting the data

Answer (score 2):

Data loading and extraction in CumulusCI is documented in [Automating Data Operations](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/stable/data.html).

The `load_dataset` task defaults to using the Bulk API or the REST API based on data volume. For small record volumes (under 2,000 records), it will default to using the REST API, and for larger volumes it will automatically switch to the Bulk API.

You can [control API selection](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/stable/data.html#api-selection) with the `api` key under each mapping step:

```yaml
Accounts:
    sf_object: Account
    api: bulk
```

Available values are `rest`, `bulk`, and `smart` (the default).